# Using a proxy with .NET 4.5 HttpClient

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.5

I'm troubleshooting a bug with a service I call through .NET's HttpClient, trying to route the request through a local proxy (Fiddler), but my proxy settings seem to not be taking effect.

Here's how I create the client:

```
private HttpClient CreateHttpClient(CommandContext ctx, string sid) {
    var cookies = new CookieContainer();

    var handler = new HttpClientHandler {
        CookieContainer = cookies,
        UseCookies = true,
        UseDefaultCredentials = false,
        Proxy = new WebProxy("http://localhost:8888", false, new string[]{}),
        UseProxy = true,
    };

    // snip out some irrelevant setting of authentication cookies

    var client = new HttpClient(handler) {
        BaseAddress = _prefServerBaseUrl,
    };

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
        new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    return client;
}
```

then I send the request by:

```
var response = CreateHttpClient(ctx, sid).PostAsJsonAsync("api/prefs/", smp).Result;
```

Request goes straight to the server without attempting to hit the proxy.  What did I miss?

Comment: Is your service under test on your local machine? Consider proxy bypassing for local addresses.

Comment: By the way, creating `HttpClient` instances is expensive. You should reuse instances whenever possible. There are a few blog posts that talk about this reachable using Google.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ah, The BaseAddress I was pointing to was `http://localhost:8081`.  Turns out that despite setting BypassOnLocal to false, evidently localhost is still special enough that it bypasses the proxy.

I added a domain binding in IIS, host file entry to point that domain to 127.0.0.1, used newly created domain, now it works.

Comment: I'm getting a Bad Request - Invalid Host Name when I put the . after localhost

Comment: @DarrelMiller I get no changes after i add localhost. 
`<system.net>
    <defaultProxy>
      <proxy bypassonlocal="False" usesystemdefault="True" proxyaddress="http://localhost.:8888" />
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>`

Answer (score 55):

This code worked for me:

```cs
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;

var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    Proxy    = new WebProxy(Address: "http://localhost:8888", BypassOnLocal: false),
    UseProxy = true
}
```

Note that I am not using the [`WebProxy` constructor overload that accepts `string\[\] bypassList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webproxy.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-net-webproxy-ctor(system-string-system-boolean-system-string())), but your code does - perhaps that's the problem?

Comment: Removing the string array worked for me too. I had to an entry to HOSTS to get the proxy to work on localhost.

Comment: You just saved my day ^_^

Answer (score 3):

Is Fiddler configured to capture traffic from all processes? Look at the status bar where you see "Capturing". It should show "All Processes" next to it. If it shows "Web browsers", click it and change it to all processes. This could be different depending on the version of Fiddler you use.