# 'UTF8' is not a supported encoding name

Tags: c#, utf-8, spotify

So I'm just playing around with Spotify's Web API and I'm trying to access my top played tracks. Although I've encountered a problem I've been trying to solve for a couple of hours now but I can't find an answer.

When I try to deserialize my response, I get the follwing error:

> 'UTF8' is not a supported encoding name. For information on defining a custom encoding, see the documentation for the Encoding.RegisterProvider method.
>   Parameter name: name
>   The character set provided in ContentType is invalid. Cannot read content as string using an invalid character set.

The ContentType is `application/json; charset=UTF8`

Any ideas?

Here's my request code:

```
private static HttpClient GetHttpClient()
{
    HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler() {
        AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate
    };
    var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
    return httpClient;
}

public async Task<SearchArtistResponse> GetSelfTopAsync(string type, string userName)
{
    var httpClient = GetHttpClient();
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", GetAccessToken(userName));

    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append(ApiUrl);
    sb.Append($"/me/top/{type}");
    var query = sb.ToString();
    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(query);

    var spotifyResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SearchArtistResponse>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
    return spotifyResponse;
}
```

Comment: I think this is just a bug in the Spotify Web API, sending charset=UTF8 instead of charset=utf-8 for this endpoint. It is filed here: https://github.com/spotify/web-api/issues/291

Comment: I solved a similar problem by [specifying the proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16526689/86967).

Comment: You could just read it in advance and then fix the error before giving it to the deserializer...

Answer (score 30):

Are you using .net core?

You will need to add the following code to make the encodings available in .NET desktop available in your environment:

```
System.Text.EncodingProvider provider = System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance;
Encoding.RegisterProvider(provider);
```

More info on `CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance` can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.codepagesencodingprovider.instance(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: No, I'm using .NET 4.5 @Sephr

Comment: So that's  not the case... anyone else?

Comment: This fixes all encoding errors except of : System.ArgumentException: ''iso-2022-cn' is not a supported encoding name. For information on defining a custom encoding, see the documentation for the Encoding.RegisterProvider method.'

Comment: This solved an encoding error I was receiving when using an external .dll that was throwing an encoding error

Comment: Fixed the problem here.

Comment: after adding this line , httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() also works automatically for encoding like windows-1252 which was throwing exception before that and there is no need to add byte array logic extraction and then converting directly using specific encoding.

Answer (score 20):

The problem should be a validation of response header `Content-Type` ,that occur when you call `ReadAsStringAsync()`, if you call `ReadAsByteArrayAsync()` instead and parse to string

```
(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString())
```

that will gonna work!!!

Comment: Might be best to actually check for that "UTF8" string in the bytes you receive to ensure it's _meant_ to be UTF-8, and only fix it if you need to fix it.

Comment: There is also `Encoding.WebName`, that might be even more exact in this case

Comment: You made my day :)

Answer (score 1):

I had a same problem while I was trying to get an answer from my API which is built in PHP using C# service. I could fix the issue by changing "charset=UTF8" to "charset=\"UTF-8\"" on the PHP side(the api that sends result to the C# service). Hope this helps someone.