# Unable to receive response using RestEase

Tags: c#, .net, rest, encoding, utf-8

The response received is the following:

```
'UTF8' is not a supported encoding name. For information on defining a custom encoding, see the documentation for the Encoding.RegisterProvider method.
Parameter name: name
The character set provided in ContentType is invalid. Cannot read content as string using an invalid character set.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['UTF8' is not a supported encoding name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39065988/utf8-is-not-a-supported-encoding-name)

Comment: Are you use .net core or "full" framework?

Comment: @AntonGorbunov - full framework. I don't think it's a duplicate because this problem has to be solved through RestEase rather than HttpClient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that the server returns the wrong charset name in header. Instead `charset=utf-8` it set `charset=utf8`.

And in the point of deserialization, the `HttpClient` (RestEase use it) does not understand what encoding to use.

To solve the problem, you need to add a new provider that will point to the usual UTF8 encoding.

You should add code at "global" level (e.g. `Main` method):

```
EncodingProvider provider = new CustomUtf8EncodingProvider();
Encoding.RegisterProvider(provider);
```

And class, witch return UTF8 encoding for wrong charset name:

```
public class CustomUtf8EncodingProvider : EncodingProvider
{
    public override Encoding GetEncoding(string name)
    {
        return name == "utf8" ? Encoding.UTF8 : null;
    }

    public override Encoding GetEncoding(int codepage)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I check it like this

```
EncodingProvider provider = new CustomUtf8EncodingProvider(); 
Encoding.RegisterProvider(provider); //If comment this row - you get exception "'UTF8' is not a supported encoding name...", if uncomment - it works good
Console.WriteLine(Encoding.GetEncoding("utf8").GetString(new byte[]{0x31,0x32,0x33}));
```

**Note**

It works in .net 4.6 or higher only