# Http request getting proxy response

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, webapi

I am developing an asp.net core 5 api (1) which needs to get data from another api .net for 5 (2) also developed by me. When I test the 2 api from postman I get a satisfactory response. But from 1 I get a proxy error. I am behind a proxy, the exceptions are all set. The 1 app is local from iisexpress. The 2 app is in the intranet in another server that I test from postman and is OK. There is no authentication requirement in 2. Thanks for any help beforehand.

Comment: You need some code, and in that code you need to authenticate with your proxy server. Hope this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16526689/using-a-proxy-with-net-4-5-httpclient

Answer (score 0):

It looks like HttpClient gets the proxy but not the exceptions so

```
var client = new HttpClient( new HttpClientHandler{ UseProxy = false});
```

solves the problem. Maybe configuring HttpProxy.DefaultProxy also solves this but I didn't find documentation for this. Hope it helps.